# Lightbox jQuery Conflict Navigation Issue Responsive Theme

Tags: responsive-design, lightbox, jquery

A novice here!

I am using Lightbox on my website for images. Also, I am using a responsive theme so the navigation bar in the header turns into a dropdown list if the width of the screen reduces beyond a fixed point and turns into the usual navigation once the size is restored.
The issue that is arising in this case is that whenever I click over a photo and the Lightbox comes into play, the navigation dropdown menu will be displayed by default and will not go away unless I refresh. Usually, either the normal navigation menu or the dropdown are displayed one at a time, but after Lightbox both are displayed simultaneously. How do I deal with this? I believe there is a jQuery conflict, but I am not sure how to deal with it! Please help me with it, along with the new code.
Thank you in advance!

This is the jQuery code of Lightbox:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/lightbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I have renamed the files. The first one would be the version of jQuery.

Here is the other code in the file which I guess is conflicting:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: well it is a little urgent if you can help me? Thank you